# convert html file to pdf using dompdf

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf

How do I properly use dompdf to convert html files into pdf. I'm doing something like this:

```
<?php
require_once("lib/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

$file = "checkout.html"; 

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html_file($file);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");

?>
```

But I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Inline_Frame_Decorator::normalise() in C:\wamp\www\pos\php\lib\dompdf\include\table_frame_decorator.cls.php on line 252
```

How do I solve this, please enlighten me. Thanks.

**Update**
Here are the contents of checkout.html

```
<table border="0">
    <th colspan="10">Product</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <!--<th>Discount</th><!-- commented out jan 21--> 
    <th>Subtotal</th>





        <!-- fetch values from reports and prod_table using the qtysoldfetcher query-->




<tr>
<td  colspan="10">Boysen</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>900</td>
<!-- <td></td>  --><!-- commented out jan 21--> 
<td>3600</td>
</tr>








<h3 id="wyt">Sales Transaction Summary</h3><a href="pdfqtysold.php"><img id="tablez" src="../img/system/icons/Oficina-PDF-icon.png"></img></a>

<tr>
<td>Total Bill: </td>
<td colspan="8">3600</td>

<!--added jan 19 -->

</tr>

<tr>

<td>Amount paid: </td>
<td colspan="8">900</td>
</tr>



<tr>
<td>Change: </td>
<td colspan="8"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Credit: </td>
<td colspan="8">2700</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Date: </td>
<td  colspan="8">2011-01-28 11:13:52</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Bought by: </td>
<td  colspan="8">Asakura, Yoh</td>
</tr>
<!--end-->

 </table>
```

Comment: I was update my answer. You can check.

Comment: Your html is still horribly structured. dompdf is somewhat flexible in dealing with structural problems, but not *that* much. The following document (based on your own) will render correctly: http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug_tests/so4829828.htm

Comment: if i wants to use a url then wht is the code updation. ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*checkout.html* is valid ? Is there any table and unclosed tags ?

There was an answer on Google Groups :

1. check to see if you have any  unclosed tags within the the table; 
   DOMPDF can have trouble when your HTML  isn't well-formed
2. check for  table-related display types in your  CSS on elements
   where the table  structure hasn't been explicitly  outlined

**UPDATE :**

Your checkout.html file ISN'T valid. There is a problem :

```
<!--<th>Discount</th><!-- commented out jan 21-->
```

*Line 5, Column 31: invalid comment declaration: found name start character outside comment but inside comment declaration*

Your comment block isn't closed. You can use this line :

```
<!--<th>Discount</th>--><!-- commented out jan 21-->
```

Comment: tried removing all of those comments but still it says the same kind of error.

Comment: can you try adding `<html>` , `<head>` tags etc. And check http://validator.w3.org/check

Comment: th elements should still be in a tr; h3 element inside the table but not in a td; some rows have 13 cells, some have only 9 (though I don't think this last will cause any problem)

Comment: @PuzzledBoy , just get content of your url (like `file_get_contents($url)`and than use `$dompdf->load_html($content)` instead of `$dompdf->load_html_file($url)` . It should work.

Comment: @Eray Sir i have tried but not solving the issue.. My problem is here  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086731/errors-and-warnings-with-dompdf-while-pdf-creating-with-url

Comment: +1 for this. I had same issues. Some unclosed tags i had and once i went through them and fixed them, it worked well. Thanks @Eray