# how to create and download pdf file using php?

Tags: php

I am doing a project in which I have to get the data from a form and assemble them and download them as a pdf file.
Getting the data part is over.
I am not able to assemble the data and download it as a pdf file.
Please help me.
And it would be helpful if I can get the codes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829828/convert-html-file-to-pdf-using-dompdf

Comment: Look what i found on Google: http://www.ajaxline.com/10-best-libraries-for-generating-pdf

I use often fpdf (fpdf.org) and it is full with examples.

Comment: Use tcpdf, npdf Or windows print function

Comment: @Stefan your right FPDF is fairly good and easy to use.+1

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DOMPDF](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/), which is a HTML to PDF convetor or [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) extention